# Visual Studio 2015 - Adding Reference to class library C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to add references to class libraries under my Web Forms solution. I added several class libraries to the main solution (via File -> New Project -> Add to solution). When I tried to add references to them (both from the solution explorer window and the File menu), I received a popup stating simply: "Cannot add reference to ," with no additional error messages.

I verified that all projects are using the same version of the .NET Framework (4.5, NOT the client version) and the same target architecture (x64), as I have seen in other Stack Overflow posts.

I did try and add the reference via browse, and added the DLLs from the /bin/debug folder, and that actually worked. The namespaces were picked up and even shown in intellisense. My concern here is breaking these references during release builds and deployments.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you at least post a screen shot?

Comment: Hi Emmanuel N, I added a screenshot to my original post.

Comment: When I've had this in prior versions of VS, restarting VS solved it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround for this problem.

When you head over to your solution and add a new project, you'll automatically be directed in the `Web` category. Instead head over to the `Windows` tab and pick that Class Library instead.

Comment: Yes, I was tinkering around and determined that I had selected the wrong kind of class library. Thanks!